# Is it mentioned why God protected the Qur'an from corruption but not the Bible?

Tags: quran, allah, authenticity, bible

In Islam it is believed that the Bible was revealed by God but was then corrupted by man.

Does Islam provide an account of why God protected the Qur'an from corruption but not the Bible?

Comment: I don't think Qur'an explicitly makes an argument for it, but common argument is, it is the last revelation and it should be protected so that each generation can benefit from it.

Comment: That explains why god protected the Qur'an from corruption but it doesn't explain why he didn't also protect the Bible.

Comment: There is a subtle difference that people tend to forgo. The bible is a perfectly valid religious text. It's not in ANY way corrupted. It has been modified a little. In other words, the bible is not God's word, but the word of God.

Answer (score 2):

Through empirical evidences we know that there are variations within the Bible. These different variations are sometimes conflicting with other variations.<sup>3</sup>

Different Churches have different views on which versions are correct. Unlike that of Christianity according to the two major sects that make up the majority of Muslims, Sunni and Shi'a Muslims both agree the Qur'an we have to date is either the exact same text or very similar only differentiating in dialect.

[Background information to help non-Muslim readers understand the Islamic stance on the reliability of the Bible.]

Within hadith we are told why Jews and Christians have edited their text: <sup>[1](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/96/90)</sup>

> Narrated Ubaidullah:
>   Ibn `Abbas said, "Why do you ask the people of the scripture about anything while your Book (Qur'an) which has been revealed to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) is newer and the latest? You read it pure, undistorted and unchanged, **and Allah has told you that the people of the scripture (Jews and Christians) changed their scripture and distorted it, and wrote the scripture with their own hands and said, 'It is from Allah,' to sell it for a little gain.** Does not the knowledge which has come to you prevent you from asking them about anything? No, by Allah, we have never seen any man from them asking you regarding what has been revealed to you!"

In Surah Al-Hijr [15:9] Allah (swt) has written:

> We have, without doubt, sent down the Message; and We will assuredly guard it (from corruption).

So why has Allah (swt) protect the Qur'an but not the Bible?

According to Islamic perspective, this whole world is nothing more but to test us. Allah (swt) put in the Bible a promise (a test). A promise to those who try to tamper His words in the Bible that they would face hell fire. <sup>2</sup>

So to sum it up Allah protected the Qur'an but not the Bible, as for the Bible it was a test to see if people were truly "God fearing" and would stand strong to Allah's tests. So he gave the people of the book (Jews and Christians) a test and to put it simply they failed. Allah (swt) protected the Qur'an, indicating that this test was no longer existed for the Muslims.

Sources:

1: [Sahih al-Bukhari 7363 Book 96, Hadith 90](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/96/90)

2: KJV, Rev. 22:18-19

3: The Orthodox Corruption of Scripture [Book by Bart D. Ehrman]

Comment: So why doesn't God test Muslims to see if they're up to the challenge that Jews and Christians failed?

Comment: @Daniel my answer provides the explanation to that, read the part under, "In Surah Al-Hijr [15:9] Allah (swt) has written:" Note, "We will assuredly guard it (from corruption)." is in reference to that Muslims will not be challenged like the Jews or Christians, as God is guard it from corruption.

Comment: @Opcode I believe he's asking `why not?` why are Muslims exempt from this test?

Comment: @masfenix I'm trying to explain that, but I fear that I'm not making sense in explaining it, perhaps you can clarify what exactly my previous comment is missing for the explanation? :-)

"Why doesn't God test Muslims to see if they're up to the challenge that Jews and Christians failed?" I assume the test referred to is the test that their holy books would stand from corruption, God from the Islamic perspective does not test Muslims the same way as the Jews, Christians (and other Abrahamic religions) because he assures Muslims their holy book is protected from being corrupted in any manner.

Comment: Should I edit the answer to mention that this is implicitly derived, and not of an explicit nature?

Comment: No textual variants among quran? Any ways to verify it? Just recently some quran only movement claim of some textual variants and some guy are killed.

Comment: While not to commit a logical fallacy, the two major sects of Islam (sunni, and shia) both agree there is only one Qur'an. By textual variants that does not concern the Qur'an, but mus'haf in which the Qur'an is transcribed on to. I would be sceptical of what some obscure sect says about the Qur'an, as there likely is no supporting evidence seeing if there was one of the two dominate sects would have likely already found and addressed it.

Comment: The reffrence from revelations refers to the book of revelations, not the whole bible. Out of context.